# Is there a recommended way of having an input bar in a Bootstrap panel heading?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a search box in my panel header and I've floated them both and clearfixed to get them both onto the same line, as shown:
[image: Picture of result]
It's functional, but it's not nice. That title is irritating me (If you don't immediately notice in the image, the vertical alignment is really off-putting and it'd be more suitablr at the bottom or level with the input field) and I don't want to make it bigger since my site uses a *lot* of these panels and I want it to look at least somewhat uniform.

So that's led me to think that **surely** someone has done this before, and there may be a way built into Bootstrap to handle something like this, or if not can anyone suggest a solution that's not too bloated with tonnes of classes or hacky vertical aligns?

I've dropped my code below but it's pretty predictable and fairly generic Bootstrap usage.

Edit: I've tried class "input-sm", it helps but there's still a noticeable alignment issue.

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">A title</h3>
            <div class="input-group pull-right col-lg-6">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adjust your line-height on the panel-title:

```
.panel-title{
   float:left;
   line-height: 26pt;   
}
.panel-heading .input-group{
   padding-right: 0;    
}
```

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/xvDB9